# What legitimate, legal use does the application, Access Prompt, have?

Tags: software-center

When I download the Ubuntu Software Centre Application, another application, Access Prompt, surreptitiously downloads at the same time. When I uninstall the Access Prompt application, it also uninstalls the Ubuntu Software Center app. Why is Canonical supporting an application that helps hackers steal people's private information by circumventing their security passwords? I bet that the majority of Ubuntu users doesn't even know that the Access Prompt app is on their system. When I tried to leave a review of the app on the Ubuntu download center, the app review spins eternally, and leaving a review/warning is impossible. Is anyone at Canonical reviewing these apps for security and legal purposes? This app is a hacker's dream.

**Clarification:**
Yes, the Ubuntu Download centre is already installed when I downloaded (and later bought a disc) Ubuntu. After having hacker problems for about a year, I look at everything on my system and if it looks suspicious, I uninstall it. When I found the application, Access Prompt, on my system, I found that it is available from the download center, but I don't like it and I chose to uninstall the application. When I uninstall this app, the app for desktop access to the download center uninstalls with it. If I redownload the software center app, the Access Prompt app also installs even though I don't want it. This happens every time I try to get rid of the app, Access Prompt, and I have been trying to rid myself of this app for several weeks now. This is how the access prompt app gets past my firewall and onto my system, as I have it blocked. This app, as far as I can tell, does nothing but steal people's passwords, undermining their security. How can I get rid of this nightmare app, Access Prompt, and still be able to keep the application to download apps from the Ubuntu Software Centre? I think Canonical should check the Access Prompt app, as I tried to leave a review and of course leaving any kind of review is impossible as the review space is unavailable/not working. I appreciate any help anyone is willing to provide as this hacker has made me miserable for the past year and has also spread to my relative's operating systems before I was aware that he was in my system.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this application? Or the executable name?

Comment: It is a gui tool to allow you to use your keys. https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GnomeKeyring?action=show&redirect=GnomeKeyring

Comment: What does it "surreptitiously" download? Have you monitored it?

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: If you have had hacker problems, how do you know it didn't compromise this "Access Prompt"? You aren't even calling it by its right name, how do we know you're competent enough make this judgement? You haven't shown any data to back up this claim. How about IO statistics for this application? Wireshark dumps? A reproduction on a clean, fresh system?

Comment: Access Prompt is the name that shows up on my system under the icon for this application. How competent do I have to be to uninstall this app and watch the other app,the download centre dissapear? This happens every time. I don't have a grudge against an app, that would be ridiculous! I'm saying this app is being used by a hacker, what other use does it have, to invade my system.

Comment: I have had this happen every time I install Ubuntu from download and later from disc. This also happens with Windows OS. I'm running out of OS! I have Dbanned my hard drive more than once! I remove the RAM and this hacker turns off my computer, as he has me locked out of the virtual technology in the BIOS! I know a hacker when I have one, I'm not stupid and I'm not just dissing someone's app(what is the legit. purpose of that app, no one has ever told me.

Comment: By the way, what is the "right name" for Access Prompt?

Comment: Did it ever occur to you that this "Access prompt" might be a [necessary part of running certain aspects of your system](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9399161/), and that is why it gets installed alongside the software center? If you are so paranoid that you cannot trust the default software that comes from Ubuntu then perhaps Ubuntu is not for you. (btw, the package name is `gcr`)

Comment: I have screen shots of this hacker taking over my system. Are you people so crazy as to think that Ubuntu is unhackable? I like Ubuntu, but there is not a system anywhere that is unhackable! What necessary use does an app that allows people to circumvent other people's passwords and security have in running any part of Ubuntu? Explain it to me while this hacker takes over my system!

Comment: So far, I have had nothing but criticism for having this problem in the first place and NO HELP WHATSOEVER FROM ANYONE IN SOLVING THIS PROBLEM! Anyone interested in seeing my screen shots?

Comment: Also, I can't get the "report a problem" app to work. It just spins and spins but won't open.

Comment: @StephanieRitchey sorry Stephanie but to me ... your actions seem to be the problem... deleting key components will delete anything related to that key component. The default software in Ubuntu related to system files is safe, secure and needed for a working system. You stop a hacker with 2 things: 1 you lock down your incomming traffic with your router and not your OS. 2. you use a good password for your accounts. `Are you people so crazy as to think that Ubuntu is unhackable? ` There you go wrong: a default Ubuntu is as secure as it gets. Your password is your 2nd line of defense.

Comment: I am not claiming Ubuntu is not hackable but Linux in itself is as secure as any OS can be. User actions are what get a system hacked. For someone to get onto your system remotely you need to open ports and install software where someone can use it to connect to your system, like a webserver, VNC or something similar. Both are NOT installed or open in a default system.

Answer (score 4):

Access Prompt is a security feature that is used when accessing your PC remotely or install or updating/upgrading either via Terminal or Unity/Nautilus/Gnome.  If it requires a password input from user, it'll bring either screens below up depending on how your input method is.

Access Prompt has many dependencies and is a dependant of other system processes.
When we type in `apt-cache depend gcr` into a terminal we see we see what Access Prompt is dependency of:

```
$ apt-cache depends gcr
gcr
  |Depends: dconf-gsettings-backend
  Depends: <gsettings-backend>
  dconf-gsettings-backend
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libgcr-base-3-1
  Depends: libgcr-ui-3-1
  Depends: libglib2.0-0
  Depends: libgtk-3-0
  Depends: dbus-x11
    dbus-x11:i386
  Breaks: gnome-keyring
  Breaks: gnome-keyring:i386
  Replaces: gnome-keyring
  Replaces: gnome-keyring:i386
  Conflicts: gcr:i386
```

When you use `apt-cache rdepend gcr` we find what processes Access Prompt or gcr needs to run

```
$ apt-cache rdepends gcr
gcr
Reverse Depends:
  gnome-keyring
  gcr:i386
  ubuntu-gnome-desktop
  seahorse
  gnome-keyring
```

To further expand on Access Prompt, it also accesses Sudoers file list.  As it checks to see if your actually who you say you are.  The only one true way to remove this function is to simply `root` your Ubuntu Computer.  I would HIGHLY suggest against this.
Access Prompt is your last means of defense when it comes to protecting your goods on an unencrypted drive.  Your password prevents unauthorized use from people who want your goodies!

[image: Terminal use of Access Prompt]

[image: GUI use of Access Prompt]

Comment: To be precise, that GUI dialog is for polkit privileges, not `sudo` privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Access prompt is an integral part of the operating system with which you grant programs the permission to install software or change your system. It is not a hacking tool and does not give your passwords away.